# Any group action of a group of order $7$ on a set $S$ of order $2014$ has at least 3 fixed points.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We claim that

> Any group action of a group of order $7$ on a set $S$ of order $2014$ has at least 3 fixed points.

Let $O_{x_i}$ denote the Orbit of $x_i\in S$ and $\text{Stab}_{x_i}$ the stabilizer of $x_i\in S$.

Then by the class equation
\begin{align}
|S|=&\sum_{i}|O_{x_i}|\\
=&\sum_{i}\frac{|G|}{|\text{Stab}_{x_i}|}\\
=&\sum_{i}\frac{7}{|\text{Stab}_{x_i}|}.
\end{align}
Since $7$ is prime, $|Stab_{x_i}|=1$ or $7$.
Hence,
$$|S|=\sum_{i}\frac{7}{|\text{Stab}_{x_i}|}=\sum_i 7+\sum_i 1.$$

Therefore, we can conclude that $|S|$ is equal to some sum of $1's$ and $7's$.

However, from here I'm not sure how to show that there exists at least $3$ fixed points of $X$.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to get to the conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $N_1$  be the number of $1$s. The last equation implies that
$$N_1\equiv \lvert S\rvert\mod 7.$$

Comment: From that congruence we have that $N_1\equiv 2014\mod 7\iff N_1\equiv 5\mod 7$. Does this imply that $N_1=5$? Furthermore, what do the number of $1s$ tell us about the fixed points of the group action?

Comment: As $N_1\ge 0$, it implies $N_1\ge 5$. $N_1$ is the number of fixed points. I don't see why it is asserted there are at least $3$ points, as they might have said $5$.